# Rails 3 routes with extended regex :constraints - bug?

Tags: regex, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I have the following route in my Rails 3 app.

```
post 'games/:id/:task/:card_id' => 'games#perform', :as => :perform
```

...which allows, obviously, such requests as `button_to("Foo", {card_id=>2, :action=>:perform, :task=>"foo"})`, mapping to the URL `/games/1/foo/2`.

I'd like to restrict the set of tasks the route matches. The [Rails API docs](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionDispatch/Routing) indicate that "Constraints can include the ‘ignorecase’ and ‘extended syntax’ regular expression modifiers". However, the following works as expected:

```
post 'games/:id/:task/:card_id' => 'games#perform', :as => :perform, :constraints => {:task => /(foo|bar)/}
```

But the following doesn't:

```
post 'games/:id/:task/:card_id' => 'games#perform', :as => :perform, :constraints => {:task => /(foo|
                                                                                                 bar)/x}
```

In the latter case, the `button_to` link above produces the URL: `/games/perform?card_id=2&task=foo`.

Is this a bug, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, there's a bug in the `RegexpWithNamedGroups` processing for Ruby 1.8.x because it fakes the named regexp groups syntax of 1.9 in a way that is incompatible with regexp modifiers.

The problem here is that with 1.8 Rails uses a simple index of the paren group within the regexp to map to the name.  When you add a modifier to a regexp, internally this creates an additional group which throws the index off by one.

Workaround right now is to use 1.9, or no modifier.

Comment: I want to confirm it's still a bug in HEAD first, and right now HEAD isn't running for me.  I'll add it though.